# asp.net core controller - Return string as valid json

Tags: c#, json, string, asp.net-core, controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
public string GetString()
{
    return "abc";
}
```

When I use the method above in an asp.net core controller the result is not formatted as json and the content type is text/plain. While every non-primitive result type is indeed formatted as json. How can I achive the same for string as return type?

Comment: Not helpfull and in context of JsonSerializer simply wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your return value is not a valid json, but you can do the following to change the content type only

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetString()
    {
        return new JsonResult("abc");
    }
}
```

Or you can inherit from `Controller` instead of `ControllerBase`

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetString()
    {
        return Json("abc");
    }
}
```

Comment: Both works. Thank you. But is there a way to keep string as result type and modify the way how asp.net core treats it? Maybe something like modifying/configuring the formatters used in background?

Comment: "abc" is not valid json string it doesnt make any sense to send an invalid json string

Answer (score 0):

your "abc" is not valid json string and it doesnt make any sense to return an invalid json string as a json content.

but if you want to return as an action output a valid json string, for example

```
var jsonString = "[\"abc\"]";

//or
var jsonString = "{\"name\":\"abc\"}";
```

you can use this syntax

```
return Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```

or if you use a minimal API

```
 return Results.Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```

UPDATE

But if for some reasons you want to have a string as  a json string, your code should be like this

```
var jsonString = "\"abc\"";

//or
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("abc");

return Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```

Comment: What I care for as valid json is, what the JsonSerializer class produces. And it accepts "abc" as valid json, but not abc

Comment: @WolfDonner "abc" is not a valid json, it is just a string

Comment: Maybe, but you miss what is important as solution to my problem. As said, what .net core JsonSerializer class produces and accepts is relevant. I have no intention in programming my own to conform a probable standard you are refereing to